# Combined vim modeline + emacs local-variables line on a single line

Tags: vim, emacs

Is it possible to have a single line in a file that acts as both a [vim modeline](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Modeline_magic) and an [emacs local variables line](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/LocalVariables)? If so, what would the syntax look like?

I realize that I can do it with two lines: by putting the emacs local-variable line as the 1st line of the file, and the vim modeline as the 2nd line (or 3rd, 4th, or 5th, if the `modelines` is unchanged from its default value); for example, for the case of an HTML file, like this:

```
<!-- -*- mode: Text; fill-column: 100 -*- -->
<!-- vim: set textwidth=100 : -->
```

But I’m wondering if I can put both on the same single line and still have vim and emacs parse them as expected—and if so, what the syntax would be.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it’s possible; you can do something like this:

```
<!-- -*- mode: Text; fill-column: 100 -*- vim: set textwidth=100 :-->
```

…and then if you open that file in emacs and check the value of `fill-column`, you’ll see that it's been set to `100` as expected; and open it in vim and check the value of `textwidth` and you’ll see that it’s been set to `100` as expected.